# Use interstitial ad format as a rewarded ad (Facebook Audience Network)

Tags: android, ads, mobile-application, facebook-audience-network

I've got a normal(non-gaming) app on the Play Store which has some premium features and I have currently implemented a system that temporarily unlocks the said features after a user(non-premium) agrees to watch an Ad.
Currently the ads are provided by AppLovin but I aim to switch to Facebook Audience Network instead.

As far as my understanding of FAN goes; the **rewarded video** ad format is only for gaming apps and as such I can't see it as an option when creating a placement for my app.

Would it be okay policy-wise to use an **interstitial** placement for this purpose?

I've read the 3 "policies" on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/ad-formats/interstitial/ and the don't seem to mention anything on this.

Has anyone done this? Any alternatives?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I tried it but ended up removing it as FAN never really loaded any ad into that ad space. So it's just banner ads "for now".

Comment: I have the exact same problem. There is no way to contact google Admob, as they provide no support. And Facebook support team can't do anything, as this isn't their platform. I think the integration between the two is simply incompatible, what a mess. I also tried native ads and they don't work either. Good to know that normal banners work though.

Comment: It appears we can't use Rewarded interstitial ads in non-gaming apps. I received the following response for Meta:

Rewarded interstitial ads are offered to apps registered in the App Store/ Play Store as “Gaming” category.

Answer (score 0):

To maximize your ad revenue - I would advise you integrate a mediation solution (where you integrate N ad networks). General consensus is that publishers are getting relatively higher returns using [AppLovin MAX](https://try.applovin.com/max-in-app-bidding).